# Is there Any Nomenclature for names of circuit components?

Tags: circuit-design

There are lot of components is circuit named in very different manner like voltage regulator - LM7905 etc. Do different companies name them differently.

Comment: 05 in 7905 indicates the regulated output voltage i.e. 5 V

Comment: See also [Is there any reasoning behind component names?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/19395/is-there-any-reasoning-behind-component-names)

Comment: There was a time when the first letter denoted the heater voltage and the second denoted the number of electrodes - at least in Europe - hence EC (6V, 3 electrodes) hence ECC83 for a dual triode, EF86 for a (5 electrode) pentode. Later extended for O = 0V heater, hence OC71, a 3-electrode transistor. But it wasn't used worldwide and it proved not to be sustainable when ICs came along...

Answer (score 1):

Not really, it depends on the manufacturer, how it calls its series, but often there are some parts in the name which can be easily decoded, but generally you will have to go for the datasheet.

In the example you provided the LM stands for Linear Monolithic (meaning it was integrated in a single silicon die)