# What LA4282 stands for

Tags: power-supply

Can somebody explain me the numbering system for integrated circuits.
I need an explanation for : LA4282 (not what it is, I know what it is), what each character stands for.

The one I need to replace is: LA4282 2G3 , but I found LA4282 6B2.

So if I could understand what the meaning of this naming is...

Comment: Check datasheets on both and compare, easy as that

Comment: I would guess that both parts are in the same datasheet.

Comment: datasheet does not come up with the last 3 characters (2G3 or 6B2), is just LA4282

Comment: @CorinaPetri Then there must be a table/something that says what each subtype is.

Comment: After a quick look at the datasheet there are no package / temperature variants etc so it's probably a date code and shouldn't matter for a replacement.

Comment: Related: [Is there any reasoning behind component names?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/19395/2028) and [Is there some logic in IC name prefixes?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/9321/2028)

Answer (score 2):

There's no general rule for what chip markings mean. Each vendor likes to do things their way. It just serves as a unique identifier. There's simply no point in looking for what each letter stands for.

Comment: It should be noted that leading letters generally indicate manufactuer, for example SN is TI logic, LM was National Semiconductor, AD is Analog Devices, LT(C) is Linear Tech, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The LA4282 is a 2 channel 10 watt audio amplifier which is made by Sanyo.  It comes in only one package: 12 pin inline. The numbering scheme for IC's is manufacturer specific and generally does not usually convey much information.  LA might stand for linear amplifier but that is only a guess.  You really need to consult the data sheet to determine the characteristics of the device.  The 2G3 and 6B2 might be date codes in which case you could replace one with the other. The datasheet does not give any indication of different grades or packages for this device.

Answer (score 0):

*Can somebody explain me the numbering system for integrated circuits?*

No.  Nobody can.  They are arbitrary numbers made up by someone needing to add another part into the part numbering system.  Sometimes for some chips from some manufacturers, some of the part number may have meaning.  However, the general case is that it's a arbitrary string you just have to copy to the BOM.

That said, part numbers are often broken into several fields.  There may be a leading part that tells you what overall family the device is in, a part in the middle that is a arbitrary string identifying the particular device, and a part at the end that identifies the package for devices that come in different packages.   However, even for standard packages, the package designator part of the overall number will be manufacturer specific.