# What is the difference between LT, LTC, and LTM prefixes for Linear Technologies' parts?

Tags: components

I know there are other questions about standard naming, such as [this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9321/is-there-some-logic-in-ic-name-prefixes), but so far I have not found any answers to this particular question: "What do Linear Technology's components' prefixes (e.g. **LT**, **LTC**, or **LTM**) indicate, other than that they are produced by Linear Technology?"

I asked my local sales representative, he did not know, and I felt too sheepish to pester him with arguably unimportant questions. However, I do not think it is random. It doesn't seem to correlate with device type (e.g. usually there are at least two different prefixes within a category like opamps, ADCs, etc.) Perhaps it has to do with the fabrication process? If anyone knows or has conjectures to offer I would appreciate hearing them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per [Ordering Info](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/company/ordering_info.pdf) document:

> Product Designator
>   a. LT indicates a proprietary bipolar device
>   b. LTC indicates a proprietary CMOS device
>   c. LTM indicates a proprietary μModule device
>   d. RH indicates a LTC radiation tolerant device
>   e. OP and REF are second source devices

Comment: Thank you for providing a link to that document! Now I will stop wasting time wondering :)

Comment: I believe the last time I saw this question come up, it was claimed the LT vs LTC distinction is not strict. Some LTxxx parts may be CMOS or some LTCxxxx parts may be bipolar. I haven't confirmed this by looking for actual exceptions, though.

Comment: Eugene Sh. answer is almos right but, as The Photon says, this distinction is not so strict... for example, LT8612 contains mosfet devices.

Comment: For power converter products, the CMOS vs. BiPolar rule doesn't hold up these days. Rather, LT vs. LTC indicates which of the two major power products divisions within the company designed the part.